# using reference value of pointer when using fork() in linux

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, fork

i am trying to update a value of an integer pointer throughout an application im trying to write, while using fork(). i am having trouble understanding, i suppose what is happening during the fork. does it not share the same variables from the main? how can i get the main to update its values when they are changing in the forks. here is an example I have created for an idea of what im trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changeValue(int *value)
{
  *value = *value * 2;
  printf("value in changeValue(): %d\n", *value);
}

main ()
{
  int pid;
  int *value = new int;
  *value = 10;
  printf("value in main: %d\n", *value);

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    changeValue(value);
    _exit(0);
  }

  sleep(2);
   // I want value = 20 here, but value stays = 10
  printf("value in main after fork(): %d\n", *value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the value to be updated in the parent from the child, you'll have to put it in [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#In_software) since this is a form of *inter-process communication*. I'd recommend using [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) to create the shared memory. Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

void changeValue(int *value)
{
  *value = *value * 2;
  printf("value in changeValue(): %d\n", *value);
}

int main()
{
  int pid;
  int *value = (int*)mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
  *value = 10;
  printf("value in main: %d\n", *value);

  pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
    changeValue(value);
    _exit(0);
  }

  sleep(2);
   // I want value = 20 here, but value stays = 10
  printf("value in main after fork(): %d\n", *value);
}
```

And a sample run:

```
$ ./a.out
value in main: 10
value in changeValue(): 20
value in main after fork(): 20
```

Comment: Just something I read on the manpage: MAP_ANON seems to be deprecated; use MAP_ANONYMOUS instead (see [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) )

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to use Inter-Process Communications (IPCs) to have communication between a parent and child processes. You can use Message Queues, Pipes, or Shared Memory to do that. If you use Shared Memory make sure you use Semaphores or something to ensure mutual exclusion with modifying the shared memory.

When you call fork(), it creates an identical process, but the child gets it's own memory space and heap, so variables are not shared. That is why IPCs must be used for communication between processes.

You can learn more about using shared memory here: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html
You can learn more about message queues here: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node25.html
Message queues are better to use than pipes, but if you want to learn more about pipes you can here: https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/pipe.html

Answer (score 0):

> does it not share the same variables from the main?

No. It creates a copy of the process's address space as at the moment of calling `fork().`